# how to $my_interface::class to be the same as MyInterFace::class

Tags: php

```
trait Foo {
  abstract protected function getInterface(): MyInterface

  public function foo() {
    $my_interface = $this->getInterface();

    $bar->implementsInterface($my_interface::class);
  }
}
```

The problem :  I want `$bar->implementsInterface($my_interface::class);` to be equivalent to `$bar->implementsInterface(MyInterface::class);`

How would I go about doing that? I'm a bit of a noob in php and haven't worked with OO languages in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_class`](http://php.net/get_class) function for this.

```
$bar->implementsInterface(get_class($my_interface));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can't pass around classes in php. I made the argument return MyInterface::class, and then used that for implementsInterface.